# install apk through usb on lg nexus 4

Tags: android, apk, nexus-4

I am trying to test my release apk on my LG nexus 4 before putting the apk on the play store. I don't see how to get the apk to the phone over the USB. I connect the phone over usb to my mac; in the phone folder I place the apk in the Download subdirectory. But there is no corresponding folder on the device itself.

Please do not confuse this with the debug apk with I get to the phone by simply running eclipse. But eclipse does not auto-transfer release APKs. I have to do it manually. Does anyone know how to do it manually over usb?

Comment: try `adb install your_apk.apk`

Comment: you just put your apk into anywhere in your phone. I mean in SDCard or internal memory and try or try using command 'adb install your_apk.apk Path'

Comment: you can as well send it by an email and open it on a device.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
adb install <path to .apk>
```

similarly to uninstall

```
adb uninstall your.package.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your LG Nexus 4 for the development on your MAC.

This Link will help you - http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

After doing this you will be able to directly run your app through eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You must disconnect the device from your mac before the phone can access the folder.
Try after disconnecting the device, you should find the apk at the designated folder that you created.